# Что не так с кодом или что, кроме кода, может быть не так?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Script : MonoBehaviour {

    private Light myLight;
    void start () {
        myLight = GetComponent <Light> ();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {
            myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled; 
        }
    }
}
```

Пишет это: object reference not set to an instance of an object. Сам скрипт прикреплён к Directional Light. Все как видеоуроке, но там работает, а у меня нет, свет не включается и не выключается при нажатии на space. (https://itproger.com/course/unity-csharp/3 - это тот видеоурок на всякий пожарный). Помогите.

Comment: а разве не пишется так: != вместо    "=!"

Comment: @Tode, это не булева проверка это значит  "присвоить НЕ(значение булевой переменной)"

Comment: Это плохие "уроки". Смотри официальные видео и документацию. Не нужно учится у людей которые сами не разбираются что к чему.

Comment: @ValeraKvip там, кстати, что в видео, что в приложенном скрипте всё норм написано. Поэтому не стоит сразу горячится и не принимать в счет то, что ученик не внимателен ;-)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, я в целом про такого рода видео. Лучше учится у разработчиков движка, и у людей с реальным опытом создания игр, а не у тех, кто кое как прочитал мануал и пытается пересказать его на видео.  Тем более что у юнити с этим все ок!

Comment: @ValeraKvip угумс))

Answer (score 1):

```
void Start () { // С большой буквы
```

Язык восприимчив к регистру.

Comment: у меня сейчас написано как ты написал

Comment: @Max, начни отсюда: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/67ef8sbd.aspx

Comment: Valera Kvip, спасибо большое, не заметил, что start вмеcто Start, глупая ошибка